# Can't see file information (other than the size) in status bar

Tags: windows-explorer

As of today, I can no longer see any file information in the status bar of my Windows Explorer window. I can see the number of files selected, the size and the zone. No date information.

I've tried:

1. Hiding/showing the status bar.
2. Switching settings in Organize (under Layout I only have "menu bar" and "navigation pane").
3. The usual (login/out, restart etc.)

I'm on Windows Server and I'm connection to a RDP via VPN. NB it worked yesterday and as far I'm informed, nobody has made any changes. What do I miss?